# android xml scrollview not working and layout_alignParentBottom not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

sorry for bad english

I want to have xml with items and at the botton of xml i want to have 2 buttons horizantally,
all that items i want to be able to scroll, I will give me what i tried, but i still have space at the button of xml and the elements is not scroll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_address_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/tv_address_title"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <!-- Label Label -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/tv_address_labelName"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_errorUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/require"
                android:textColor="#FF0000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_address_username"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:hint="@string/et_hint_enterLabel"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Province Label -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_province"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/tv_province"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_errorProvince"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/require"
                android:textColor="#FF0000" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/s_address_province"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_address_province"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:entries="@array/provinces"
                android:prompt="@string/s_province" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- City Label -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/tv_city"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_errorCity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/require"
                android:textColor="#FF0000" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/s_address_city"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_address_city"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:prompt="@string/s_city" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Street Label -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_street"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/tv_street"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_address_errorStreet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/require"
                android:textColor="#FF0000" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/s_address_street"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_address_street"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:prompt="@string/s_street" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Save Cancel Label -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/b_save" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/b_cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the code.  I think you have following use.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        .....
        ....
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: in your case the button will not scroll with the elemetnet, i want to keep the elemetns at button and still can be scroll with elemetns, because the elements is larg and for sure i need to scroll it